# SSRS Top N and Bottom N filter tie-breaker

Tags: reporting-services, filter, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS report with groups that filter by TOP 3 and BOTTOM 3.  In one set of data, I have a 16 way tie for bottom 3.  I want to set a "tie-breaker", so if it's not a tie, filter bottom 3 based on my original condition, but if there is a tie and more than 3 are returned, filter first by my original condition, but then filter again based on a second condition to only get 3 returned.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 3 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY PrimarySortCol, TiebreakerSortCol`?

Comment: I would like to do it from within the Filters tab of the group properties.

Comment: How do you currently filter "TOP 3" in SSRS? What expressions do you use?

Comment: In the filters panel of group properties I have Expression `=IIf(Fields!goal_3day.Value=0, 0, Fields!Actual_3day.Value/Fields!goal_3day.Value)` For operator I have chosen Bottom N and for Value I have 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up adding two extra datasets to the report.  One for Top 3 and one for Bottom 3.  That way I could just query the top 3 with a sql query.

It would be nice if I could use the built-in filter without adding datasets, but it works.